# Automatically update Vue site / PWA with new release

Tags: vue.js, nginx, progressive-web-apps

I have a Vue app that is used both in the browser and as a PWA. I would like to ensure users receive the latest version whenever updates have been pushed to the server.

I am using `Nginx`, `Django` and `vue-cli` along with `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa`.

Currently when I `npm run build` and then push the new version to the server, users get the old version of the app (in browser as well as PWA on their phones). To get the new version they do a hard refresh in the browser or for the PWA they close the app and reopen it again.

Is there a way to ensure a version check is done every time the app is loaded so that the new version is retrieved?

Comment: One approach is described at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#offer_a_page_reload_for_users, but I don't know if you have the flexibility to add in that custom code to a `vue-cli` project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the end I found this excellent article which covers how to display a notification when an update is available. The user is then able to click the notification which updates the app.

https://dev.to/drbragg/handling-service-worker-updates-in-your-vue-pwa-1pip